# Published android App with unique name not showing in playstore search

Tags: android, google-play, mobile-application, google-apps-marketplace

I have published an android app with name 'Securide' on google play store. But when I search this app with word 'Securide'; play store search only shows the apps which has word 'security' in it and my app Securide is not shown.

However when searched with package name or company name, the search returns my app. Also when searched with Securide word on google web search it finds and retun my app link.

Please help me to sort this problem so that my app is displayed when searched with its title.

Comment: Just wait for a while. Search data have to cache.

Comment: Because your app ranking is still in the bottom, it will not be on the top-list in just a week or days (if and only your app gets popular in just a day).

Comment: Thanks for the reply...  I know ranking is low....  But I think name is unique...  So I was thinking it has to show me matching names first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question - see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I have the same searching problem and this is about 5 days that I published my app. My app's name has two parts (daily gallery) and if I search just by one part (daily or gallery) app doesn't show up in the search result. This is my question.

Comment: I too am encountering the same issue.  My app name is "Whipster", and a bunch of other apps named "whisper" are showing up first.  I know google has their weighted algorithims but to me it makes no sense that if a person searches for the specific app name and it exists, then that app should show up first.  Whats the point of creating a unique name that should be easily searchable if Google is simply does not give a damn and searches for what it thinks the user meant or wants to return to the user.

Comment: Further more, if I am a user and search for an app named "Whipster"...and other apps like "Disney" or "whisper" come up first, a logical conclusion would be that "whipster" doesn't exist and then never bother to scroll down or look further for the app.  I would understand if 100s of apps named Whipster appeared, then mine would rank quite low - but even so the user would see the multiple listings and then intuitively scroll through all the "whipster" apps.  This issue has caused huge headaches as I have had dozens and dozens of users saying my app isn't on the Play store.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Play Store's algorithm does not sort by similarity to search (basically, if you search Securide it won't look for something with exactly or almost that name), instead it will look for popular apps with a slightly similar name. If you would like to send your app to someone, I recommend that you find it using your own account and send an external link at a site, blog, or YouTube channel that people can access on phones and tablets.